# MPMoviePlayerController: possible to clip bottom part of the video when using scalingMode MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Using a `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a video, with

```
[player setScalingMode: MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
```

both the top part and the bottom part of the video are clipped, but I want it **top aligned** and only keep the upper part, any solutions?
[image]
p.s. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702287/2918210), but it's answer didn't suit me, cause it didn't clip the video but my player do not occupy the screen.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayer is Deprecated, you should use AVPlayerViewController
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/

This SO has an Obj-c example:
[How to play video with AVPlayerViewController (AVKit) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift)